# Write to external storage on Android 7

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I want to write to the external storage in my Android app, but I don't seem to get the permissions right. The App runs on Android 7, so I request the permissions on runtime like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // We don't have permission so prompt the user
    int ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE = 1;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE);
}

permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // We don't have permission so prompt the user
    int ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE = 1;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE);
}
...
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
                } else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

One observation I made is that onRequestPermissionsResult seems to return that the permission was not granted, but I was also never prompted when starting the app to permit writing to external storage.

I set these permissions in the Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application>
```

The code to write to the storage is here:

```
public static void appendByteBuffer(byte[] data)
{
    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.raw";
    //filename value is "/storage/emulated/0/test.raw"
    File rawAudioFile = new File(filename);
    if (!rawAudioFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            rawAudioFile.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename, true)) {
        output.write(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

> 03-16 14:50:49.988 19145-19306/? W/System.err: java.io.IOException:
>   Permission denied 03-16 14:50:49.988 19145-19306/? W/System.err:
>   at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method) 03-16
>   14:50:49.988 19145-19306/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
>   03-16 14:50:49.989 19145-19306/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948) 03-16 14:50:49.989
>   19145-19306/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.meeter.study.AppUtils.appendByteBuffer(AppUtils.java:76) 03-16
>   14:50:49.989 19145-19306/? W/System.err:     at

Comment: **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. Use methods on `Context` (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`) or methods on `Environment` (e.g., `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`) to derive paths that are accurate for your device and user.

Comment: thanks but thats not relevant to my question @CommonsWare

Comment: Sure it is. `/sdcard/` may not be pointing where you think it is, or even exist on this device. Beyond that, does `/mydata/` exist?

Comment: Im getting the same with a programmatic way of getting the external storage. See my updated post.

Comment: Try moving the `<uses-permission>` elements above the `<application>` element, instead of below it. Android used to have some implicit rules about that sort of thing. I had hoped that they had fixed those, but that's one difference between what you have and stuff that I know works, like [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Files/FilesEditor).

Comment: I moved the permissions up but no change. I noticed I never actually get the prompt about external storage. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: "I noticed I never actually get the prompt about external storage" -- right, and I don't quite understand why. If you go into Settings > Apps > (your app) > Permissions, does the storage permission group show up, and is it granted to your app?

Comment: `rawAudioFile.createNewFile();`. Do not create the file yourself. Remove that code. The file will be created bi new FileOutputStream().

Comment: @CommonsWare the storage permissions showed up but wasn't checked. Any idea how to ensure a prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ContextCompat` instead of `ActivityCompat` for `checkSelfPermission`:

Replace:

```
permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

With:

```
permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Then, Add `onRequestPermissionsResult` method to handle ALLOW, DENY selection. Hope this helps.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // Write to the storage (ex: call appendByteBuffer(byte[] data) here)

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please grant permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't know how to use onRequestPermissionsResult, could you provide a working example?

Comment: Sure, wait a minute.

Comment: i tried this but I get the response that the permission was not granted. any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you press Deny of permission dialog?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138270/discussion-between-tahsinrupam-and-bear).

Comment: ok i so found in Android 7 if I manually go in app settings for my app, i can change these permissions so when i manually set the permissions there it works.

Comment: Yeah it will work, but when you publish an app in playstore, manually granting permission will be a hassle for the users and it is a not standard procedure.