# how get permission in android API 25 (Nougat)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.1-nougat

want to save file on storage.

i use this code to get permission in android 6.0 :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
        }
```

but in android 7 seems not working. and file not saving on storage.

what different between android 6 and 7 permissions?

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: @tim-castelijns 

so i use [ThinDownloader](https://github.com/smanikandan14/ThinDownloadManager) for download files. maybe problem be for that?

Answer (score 1):

they are the same just that in nougat file:// are not allowed 
check this [file:// scheme is now not allowed to be attached with Intent on targetSdkVersion 24 (Android Nougat).](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when creating folders and saving files with my app. It is working fine on API 18 but not directly on API 24. I figured out, that you have to allow an additional permission for the app in their settings when installed.

But you may want to follow this answer: [Write to external storage on Android 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842648/write-to-external-storage-on-android-7)